# Front speaker extremely quiet on call

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, audio

Is there any way to boost it? It seems to be louder on the rear of the phone.

I have a GT-I9505 Galaxy S4.

Answer (score 2):

Try these:

- You can turn up the volume of a call on your phone by pressing the volume buttons while in a call.
- Make sure that you are using the "earpiece" speaker setting instead of "speakerphone." (The latter would cause the volume to be louder in the back.)
- See if you can find any debris that is obstructing the earpiece speaker and carefully remove it with a small tool of necessary. (This is unlikely to greatly impact the sound/quality of the speaker.)